# ASP.NET 5 on Visual Studio 2015 addMvc method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6 to setup a web api and I have not made it very far. Once I added the line: `services.addMvc();` I got an exception saying this method is not found. I searched online and found a separate question/answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/2026087.aspx but that did not help.

My startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
```

And my project.json:

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
],
"packExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"frameworks" : {
    "aspnet50" : { },
    "aspnetcore50" : { }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc reference added successfully to your project. It also seems that you are using latest CTP 5 but reference MVC beta1 so I suggest try to use beta2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly sure you are using some incorrect packages. Try to create the default starter application that comes with VS (use the latest VS 2015) and see exactly what packages to use.

A few comments based on the contents of your`project.json` file:

1. For now, do not mix different versions of beta packages (like beta1 and beta2). That's a recipe for disaster :)
2. Beta1 is old, please upgrade

Comment: I have tried at my local end with CTP5 and beta1 dll and it is working Victor Hurdugaci.

Answer (score 4):

After I had added "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2" to project.json and saved the file my dependencies didn't automatically get restored. I had to close and reopen the solution. After I did that the packages were restored and the error went away. I'm sure there is a more simple way to restore, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: I think you can force a package restore now by right clicking on the project and clicking Restore Packages.