# ASP.Net 5: Updating 1.0 Beta8 to RC1 - IServiceCollection does not contain definition for AddMvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some code composed of an authorization api project,a common project  and an ASP.net main application project, in a single solution.   I have gone through the related project.json files and removed explicit beta8 references, and then made some other required corrections. For example, changing using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, where necessary.

I understand from the linked potential duplicate that the first thing to suspect is an invalid mixture of references in my various project.json files.  I have no beta8 references left anywhere, explicitly. Thus I do not think that the linked issue is the same.

Where I'm stuck seems like a really basic thing:

```
Error   CS1061  Build   'IServiceCollection' does not contain a
definition for 'AddMvc' and no extension method 'AddMvc' accepting a first 
argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc referenced in the project.json, and it doesn't matter if I put "using Microsoft.AspNet.mvc" in the .cs file or not the error persists.  I thought you add references in the new world order, just by adding them to project.json. If an assembly reference exists in the project.json, why does this error still occur?

My project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.0.0-*",
    "MyCompany.Common": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

The line of code that's breaking is the AddMvc one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime;
using RamSoft.Authorization.Api.Common;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using RamSoft.ITConsole.Common;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
namespace MyCompany.Authorization.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
     ...
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddInstance(_signingCredentials);
            services.AddInstance(_jwtBearerOptions);

            services.AddMvc();  // Fail.

        }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 5 on Visual Studio 2015 addMvc method not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127307/asp-net-5-on-visual-studio-2015-addmvc-method-not-found)

Comment: I already cleaned up my project.json references so it's not a duplicate.  Unless I just think I did, and there is some additional step (besides actually make the .json files correct) like "nuke all the stuff in your dnvm runtime package cache manually".

Comment: You seem to be using `"1.0.0-*"` everywhere. Is that correct? Isn't that supposed to be `"1.0.0-rc1-final"`? Also, what's in your global.json file?

Comment: My thought was that * was supposed to mean "I don't want to change this from rc1-update1 to rc1-final, or whatever, please just work". Isn't that what the * does? My solution has explicitly set the solution dnx level to 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Comment: Try going to `~/.dnx/packages` and deleting everything in there. Then in a command prompt, go to the root of your solution and execute `dnu restore`. Does it succeed? What versions of the packages get downloaded to your `~/.dnx/packages` folder? In your global.json and project.json, what runtime version is referenced, `rc1-final` or `rc1-update1`?

Comment: I have the same issue in May, 2016!

Comment: Try deleting your xproj and package caches

Answer (score 0):

You need to change dependencies on your project. here is my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  }
```

and adding `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;` in startup.cs

we can use AddMvc() atleast working for Core 1.0 rc2